# automatic switch over on integration

Tags: apex, rest

I am working on quote object integration but customer is not ready to provide end point details.
Instead of that asking me to integrate with temporary mock system and do end to end testing.
They are expecting automatic switch over without any change in the code.
Here, i am decided  to create a rest service on same sandbox and trying to invoke the service.
Is it feasible? Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: The question is a little broad. Is there a reason you don't think it's feasible? I'd suspect if you're able to implement this in a production environment you should be able to follow similar steps to implement in a sandbox.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Named Credential](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.named_credentials_about.htm&type=5&sfdcIFrameOrigin=null) in order to avoid having to change the URL. All you have to do is change the URL in the NC, and you'll use the new system.

Comment: Thank you for your idea